# OpenLDAP 2.3/2.4 concurrency issue

Tags: java, linux, ldap, openldap

Experiencing concurrency issues when authenticating and other read requests with Open LDAP (version tested 2.3.43 and 2.4.39)

When making 100 concurrent bind requests the test code takes around 150 milliseconds. Increasing this to 1000 concurrent requests sees the time taken increase to 9303 milliseconds.
So from x10 concurrent requests we are seeing a x62 increase in time taken.

Is this expected behaviour? Or is there something missing in our OpenLDAP server configuration/linux host configuration?

NOTE: We have run this test code against a Windows based Apache DS server 2.0.0 (same tree structure, etc) for comparison and against that server, the performance results where what we would normally expect (i.e. 100x takes ~80ms, 1000x takes ~400ms, 10,000x takes ~2700ms)

Settings in slapd.conf:

```
cachesize       100000
idlcachesize    300000
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=company,dc=com"
rootdn          "uid=admin,ou=system"
rootpw          secret
directory       /var/lib/ldap
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
sizelimit       100000
loglevel        256
```

Test code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
public class DirectoryServiceMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int concurrentThreadCount = 100;

        LdapContextSource ctx = new LdapContextSource();

        ctx.setUrls(new String [] { "ldap://ldap1.dev.company.com:389/", "ldap://ldap1.dev.company.com:389/" });
        ctx.setBase("dc=company,dc=com");
        ctx.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        ctx.setPassword("secret");

        ctx.setPooled(true);
        ctx.setCacheEnvironmentProperties(false);
        LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate();
        template.setContextSource(ctx);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < concurrentThreadCount; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(
                () ->  {                   
                    DirContext context = template.getContextSource().getContext("uid=username,dc=users,uid=office,dc=suborganisations,uid=ABC,dc=organisations,dc=company,dc=com",
                                                                           "password");
                    try {
                        context.close();
                    } catch(NamingException e) {}

                });

            t.start();
            threads.add(t);
        }

        boolean alive = true;
        while(alive) {
            alive = false;
            for(Thread t : threads) {
                if(t.isAlive()) {
                    alive = true;
                    try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                } 
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Total time: " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

ulimit -n
131072

*** UPDATE ***
If a slight delay (e.g. Thread.sleep(1)) is added after each t.start(), then processing time of n concurrent threads drops considerably.

Comment: The short answer is 'yes'. Response time versus load isn't linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A longer answer is if you are using BDB as the database then you will likely see linear scaling problems above a certain number of concurrent requests. BDB has its own db_config file that you can configure to provide better performance characteristics.  You could also consider change to MDB which was specifically written for open ldap and has better linear scaling with minimal configuration.

You should also consider limiting the number of concurrent connection made by setting the jndi ldap connection pool sizes against the LDAPContextSource:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.initsize", 2);
map.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize", 2);
map.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize", 2);
ctx.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(map);
```